# Count Nodes in BST

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to create a function that counts the number of nodes inserted in a BST. I am not sure why I'm getting bad access. I would really appreciate your help!

I am trying to implement totl, which counts the number of words in a tree, including the duplicated words that weren't added to the tree (but incremented m_count)
However, I am getting bad access for this:

```
int totl(T * curr) const
{
    if(root==nullptr)return 0;
    else
    {
        return root->m_count + totl(root->m_left) + totl(root->m_right);
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @evg i mimized the text but it would be hard to find the problem when i dont provide the code

Comment: Please provide a **reproducible** (compilable and executable) example. Now we don't even see the declaration of `totalWords_aux`.

Comment: @Evg thank you for your clarification, I just added the class and function declarations

Comment: `curr` parameter is unused in that `aux` function?

Comment: yeah i didnt use it

Comment: And where is `totalWords_aux` definition? Could you post a code that can be **compiled**?

Comment: hello, I just added a compilable code to the end of the post!

Comment: Now try to think what `totalWords_aux` does. Hint: stack overflow.

Comment: i just updated totalWords_aux it was a different one, i was thinking that my base case might be incorrect which is why my recursion isn't working but it makes sense to me

Comment: How could recursion work if `curr` is not used at all? You're calling the function over and over again with **exactly the same** execution in its body. Step into it with a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: oh thats right! I just edited it and it worked, thank you so much!

Comment: You should not edit your question to insert the solution into it. That is not how this site works. You posted an answer and that's all. Leave the question as a question.

Answer (score 0):

The code should have used `curr` not `root` in the recursive function, which then is called as `totl(root)` in `main`.